# How can I present a sheet in response to a tap on a button which has also dismissed an open Menu?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing a SwiftUI view that has both `Menu` elements and `Button`s that trigger the presentation of a `sheet`.

I have noticed an odd effect where if the button-tap that usually presents the sheet occurs while a `Menu` is currently presented, the sheet does not present. Moreover, subsequent taps do not present the sheet either. When this happens, I see the following logged message:

> Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x113811a00> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x112825600> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x112825600>) which is already presenting <_UIContextMenuActionsOnlyViewController: 0x10c1183c0>.

This only happens if the tap on the modal presenting button is quick - for longer presses, it works as expected.

A complete app that exhibits this behaviour is as follows:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct menuAndButtonApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var modalIsPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 28) {
            Menu("Open Menu") {
                Text("Menu Item")
            }
            Button("Present Modal") {
                modalIsPresented = true
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented) {
            Text("Here is a sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

This looks very much like a SwiftUI bug, but I am hunting for an alternative approach or a workaround that will allow me to prevent this annoying behaviour. (One workaround I have confirmed is wrapping the button's action in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(.now() + 0.2) { }` to allow time for the context menu to be dismissed, but I'd have to do that unconditionally because I cannot detect whether the context menu is presented at any given moment.

This has been tested only on Xcode 15, and exhibits on all iOS versions I have tested (15, 16 and 17).

Screen recording example: https://imgur.com/a/r1JdZ2j

Comment: (Filed as FB13252972)

Comment: Maybe the bug has been fixed in the latest ios-17.1, because it all works well for me in my tests.
No errors, the sheet is presented when I tap on the "Present Modal" button while the
  "Menu Item" is displayed.
 
On MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1 beta, tested on real ios-17.1 devices (not Previews).
 It could be different on older systems.

Comment: It still happens for me when building with Xcode 15.1 (beta 1). Note you have to tap the Present Modal button pretty quickly for the issue to occur - I think the touch up event needs to end before the context menu is dismissed. I'll attach a video to the question.